# Ubuntu deeply hangs every time I open 30 chrome tabs and web-development software

Tags: google-chrome

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
My PC deeply hangs every time I open 30+ chrome tabs, especcialy if one of them is facebook or pages contains Google maps or maps itself. 
Sometime even mouse don't moving or moving slowly, not possible click anythings and also keyboard don't respond (hotkey not close tabs, etc).
What to do?

p.s. I have 8Gb RAM and there is no swap partition. Also I have Win7 there is no such problems, even chrome/firefox hungs, they don't hung all system

Comment: Minimize opened tab to 15 may be? or increasing RAM?

Comment: I have 8Gb of RAM and there is no swap partition
Also I have Win7 there is no such problems, even chrome/firefox hungs, they don't hung all system

Comment: often hugs even with 15 tabs

Answer (score 1):

Chrome actually eats so much amount of ram (about 1.5 Gb in my machine), check you ram usage in `system monitor` and check for which process keep using more of your ram...

I recommend you to close all unused tabs and do use firefox more. Also you need to change in swap `sysctl vm.swappiness=10`.

I hope your system will no more / less have hanging issues. If still there is problem then you need to update ram, minimum 6gb for smooth running...

Comment: thank you, but I have 8gb already, but don't have swap partition/file

Comment: In that case you need to find where is the problem? Don't compare win to linux because win run good even with 2gb ram. Check you ram usage also which process taking too much of that, what is partition format of ur HDD (NTFS or ext4) it must ext4 for ubuntu in which it installed, try using light desktop environment..

Answer (score 0):

Web Development Software meaning you might have some sort of localhost server like Apache running which as well chrome already takes up much of the ram.

I would suggest you to either upgrade your ram or decrease the number of tabs. Better go for other solutions like Firefox which do not hog onto your resources.